# Видео фон сужается на айфоне, как это исправить? В андроиде все отлично

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, canvas

На страничку html поставил видео фон, все работает на андроиде, пк ноутбуке.. но проблема появилась в айфоне - видео фон работает, все как нужно кроме одного, он сужается по ширине (а не обрезается как в андроиде). Помогите пожалуйста это исправить

Вот сам код:

```php
 <div id="video_background">
    <video class="video" muted="muted" loop="loop" autoplay="autoplay">
        <source src="videos/video.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="videos/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <canvas class="canvas"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="/js/canvas-video-player.js"></script>
<script>

var isIOS = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.platform);

if (isIOS) {

    var canvasVideo = new CanvasVideoPlayer({
        videoSelector: '.video',
        canvasSelector: '.canvas',
        timelineSelector: false,
        autoplay: true,
        makeLoop: true,
        pauseOnClick: false,
        audio: false
    });

}else {

    // Use HTML5 video
    document.querySelectorAll('.canvas')[0].style.display = 'none';

}   

</script>
```

```css
#video_background {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -100;
    background: url(images/photo.jpg) no-repeat #000000;
    background-size: cover;
}


#video_background > video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto; 
 }

 @supports (object-fit: cover) {
     #video_background > video {
         top: 0;
         left: 0;
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         object-fit: cover;
     }
 }

 .canvas,
.video {
height: 50%;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
background: #000;
z-index: 5;
}
```

Ссылка на canvas

http://www.develooping.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/html-canvas-video-player.zip

Пока что с первой проблемой костылями справился в стилях так:
Создал отдельно версию видеофона под айфон

```
//смотрю, зашли с айфона или нет (ставлю в самом верху странички перед DOCTYPE)
<?php
  $browser = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
    if ($browser == true){
    $browser = 'iphone';
  }
?>
```

Потом в теле страницы ниже указываю код видеофона. Для андроида и айфона - все почти одинаково только меняю для айфона `<video class="video"` на `<video class="video2"`

```
<?php if($browser == 'iphone'){ ?>

 id="video_background2"
    <video class="video2" muted="muted" loop="loop" autoplay="autoplay">
        <source src="videos/Scene_1_Logo.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="videos/Scene_1_Logo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <canvas class="canvas"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="/js/canvas-video-player.js"></script>
<script>

var isIOS = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.platform);

if (isIOS) {

    var canvasVideo = new CanvasVideoPlayer({
        videoSelector: '.video2',
        canvasSelector: '.canvas',
        timelineSelector: false,
        autoplay: true,
        makeLoop: true,
        pauseOnClick: false,
        loop: true,
        audio: false,
        setInterval: 30,

    });

}else {

    // Use HTML5 video
    document.querySelectorAll('.canvas')[0].style.display = 'none';

}   

</script>

<?php } ?>
```

В стилях прописываю только `.canvas,.video2` все остальное к нему не применяю

```
 .canvas,
.video2 {
height: 100%;
left: -40%;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 190%;
background: #000;
z-index: -100;
}
```

Здесь ширина в 190% это примерно и есть полная ширина видео, а `left: -40%;` устанавливает видео по центру.
В этом варианте видео обрезается по краям, нет лишних промоток и находится по центру.

Единственная сейчас проблема это цикл видео, чтобы оно постоянно воспроизводилось, а не дошло до конца и остановилось.
`loop="loop"` не работает, пробовал написать что то типа "если видео на паузе - видео плей", но это не сработало, наверное я не так что то пишу, можете подсказать как с этим справится?

```php
if (canvasVideo.pause()) {
canvasVideo.play();
}
```

Comment: покажи как на видео он сужается. непонятно.

Comment: https://ibb.co/jyqhz3j сужается по ширине

Comment: Единственное что у меня пока вышло это просто увеличить ширину видеофона в css #video_background {width: 190%; left: -40%;} (чтобы казалось что он не сужен) и используя left сдвинуть его чтобы казалось что фон стоит по центру, но в итоге появляется прокрутка в правую сторону до конца видео фона

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй использовать так (не знаю поможет или нет, у меня нет Айфона):

```
width: 100wv;
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Но к сожалению не сработало. Тот же результат как если поставить `width: 100%;`